# 'Steal minimum number of items as a thief' problem

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, greedy

One of the professors of mine asked this question;

```
Imagine a thief entering a house. In the house, there are infinitely many items
that can have only one of three different weights: 1 kg, 3 kgs, and 5 kgs. All of the items are 
discrete. The thief has a bag capacity of n kgs and strangely, he wants to steal the “smallest 
number of items”.
```

He wants us to: `Show that the greedy choice of taking the largest weight items into the bag first  fails to lead to an optimal solution`. But I claim that greedy is not failing. In any case taking as much as 5kg item is resulting in minimum number of items which is optimal. Is he wrong? I think greedy is optimal. Is there any case that greedy fails?

By the way, my solution:

```java
public int stealRecursive(int bagCapacity) {
        return stealRecursive(bagCapacity, 0);
    }

private int stealRecursive(int bagCapacity, int numberOfItemsStolen) {

    boolean canSteal5kg = bagCapacity - 5 >= 0;
    boolean canSteal3kg = bagCapacity - 3 >= 0;
    boolean canSteal1kg = bagCapacity - 1 >= 0;

    if (canSteal5kg) {
        return stealRecursive(bagCapacity - 5, numberOfItemsStolen + 1);
    }

    if (canSteal3kg) {
        return stealRecursive(bagCapacity - 3, numberOfItemsStolen + 1);
    }

    if (canSteal1kg) {
        return stealRecursive(bagCapacity - 1, numberOfItemsStolen + 1);
    }

    return numberOfItemsStolen;
}
```

Some of you stated that putting the code is not pointing anywhere, you are right I just put it to show both my effort and way of thinking. Because whenever I ask a problem without putting my code, I've been warned to show my effort first, due this is not a homework site. That's why I put my code. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Is the "greedy approach" defined somewhere? Maybe the professor and you are not having the same algorithm in mind for that word... For me, a "greedy approach" could also be to fill the sack with 1 kg elements, so you get the most elements.

Comment: @cyberbrain I've updated the question, I wrote what it is written in the assignment.

Comment: Who wrote that shown code presented as "my solution"? You or the professor? Why is that code there? The question reads like something which has to be solved by reasoning. Writing code does not seem to be the way to "Show that the greedy choice ... fails to lead to an optimal solution". What would be the behaviour of the code which verifies that? What would be the behaviour of the code which falsifies that? The code only provides example results after all. The reasoning which uses those results for providing the proof is missing, isn't it?

Comment: You would have to find one example where the professors claim is true to prove it. You could try to write code that finds solutions in different picking algorithms than the greedy one. If you want to go that way, I would recommend not to use recursion, integer division and modulo operator are sufficient here. Still I can't think of any solution where this claim could be true as two of the three sizes can be "compensated" only by a bigger number of smaller sizes.

Comment: @Yunnosch I wrote the code. I know putting the code there is not pointing anywhere but whenever I just ask a question and do not put code, someone says 'show us your effort first, this is not a hmw website'. Therefore, I put my code. Sorry if it is confusing

Comment: I actually understand that - and sorry for that quick-shot reaction of many users here. You should however rephrase your question to focus on the logical reasoning and explain what example the shown code provides, and for what input.

Comment: With 1, 3, 5 kg, and if the goal is to minimize the number of items, then it seems clear that the greedy algorithm (max weight first) is optimal. Not the case always with a different set of weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's suppose that you have "taken" as many 5k items as possible, so you end up having

```
m = capacity mod 5
```

items to be stolen and you have already stolen 5n kilograms.

Cases

## m == 0

5n

In this case you have n items and if you have stolen 1k or 3k items, then it would be worse (except for n = 0, in which case it does not make a difference whether you steal 0 items of 5 kilograms, 0 items of 3 kilograms or 0 items of 1 kilogram)

## m == 1

5n + 1

In this case you have stolen n items of 5 kilograms and you steal an item of 1 kilogram additionally.

In the case of capacity = 6, you can steal 5 + 1 kilograms or 3 + 3 kilograms, leading to the same result, but the greater n is, the greater is the advantage of the greedy approach.

## m == 2

We have 5n + 1 + 1

in the case of capacity = 7, we have 5 + 1 + 1 vs 3 + 3 + 1, but in general, greedy is better here as well.

## m == 3

5n + 3

This is much better than 5n + 1 + 1 + 1

## m == 4

5n + 3 + 1

In the case of 9, we have 5 + 3 + 1 vs 3 + 3 + 3, but in general, greedy is better

## Conclusion

In general, greedy is better, but in some cases there is a tie. The reason is that there is an infinity of items that can be stolen. If there would be finite items of 5, 3, and 1 kilograms, respectively, then we can imagine scenarios like

5k items: 1
3k items: 3
1k items: 0

capacity: 9

Now, if you take the 5k item, then you will end up with a loot of 8, instead of a loot of 9. But we have infinite 5k, 3k and 1k items, so this is not a real scenario.

Comment: Therefore greedy is optimal (just not uniquely optimal).  But the assignment is to prove greedy is not optimal - so something is amiss, possibly just in how the question and its conditions was conveyed to us.

Comment: @undefinedsymbol according to the criteria in the question, the greedy approach is always achieving at least a tie with other approaches. A counter-example would be enough to disprove all the reasoning in my answer. But it very much seems impossible to find a counter-example. So, either the professor was tricky, asking the pupils to solve the unsolvable, or there was a misunderstanding (or I'm wrong, of course)

Comment: Side node: the problem of theft is equal to problem of exchange: having a sum of money we should exchange it with as few money as possible. `1, 3, 5` is a *canonical coin system* which means that *greedy algorithm* provides an optiomal solution. https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0400